# How to enable form button after process has exited?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, process

I have an windows application developed using C#. In this application, I am creating one process. **I want to enable and disable few buttons when Process_Exited() event occures.** 
In Process_Exited() method, I have written code to enable buttons but at runtime I get error as

> "Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control
>   'tabPage_buttonStartExtraction'
>   accessed from a thread other than the
>   thread it was created on."

My code snippet is :

```
 void rinxProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     tabPage_buttonStartExtraction.Enabled = true;
     tabPageExtraction_StopExtractionBtn.Enabled = false;
 }
```

Can anyone suggest how to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to change the UI from a different thread.
Try something like this;

```
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

You shouldn't be doing much work on the UI from another thread, as the invocations are quite expensive.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Move the enable/disable lines in a separate method and call that method from rinxProcess_Exited using Control.Invoke method.

Answer (score 2):

You must make UI changes on the UI thread. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) for more details.

Here's the solution applied to your example:

```
void rinxProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => ProcessExited()));
        return;
    }

    ProcessExited();
}

private void ProcessExited()
{
    tabPage_buttonStartExtraction.Enabled = true;
    tabPageExtraction_StopExtractionBtn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: will it work on .net  2.0 framework? I think => operator was added in 3.5 framework

Comment: You're right. You have to use a delegate instead of an anonymous method if you are using the 2.0 framework. I just assumed 3.5 or higher.